# Trying to center an svg circle inside a div

Tags: html, svg

I have a simple markup:

```
 <div style="background-color:red;">
    <svg>
         <circle cx="76" cy="76" r="71" 
           style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:10" />
    </svg>
 </div>
```

See the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w46Lcdyr/)

I cannot understand the truncation of the circle at the bottom. All I want is a div with an SVG circle exactly centered. I have tried setting box-sizing and paddings but to no avail.

Comment: So you're wanting the circle to be centered within the div correct?

Comment: @HunterTurner Yes! I get a div over which I have no control with respect to its CSS. I can get its CSS and then need to exactly fit an ellipse or a circle inside it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for your problems is because you have not specified a size for your SVG.  When you don't supply a size, the browser will give it a default size of 300x150.

So your circle at `y=76` with radius 71 and stroke width 10 is going to extend down to 76+71+5 = 152, meaning the bottom of the circle is slightly clipped.

```html
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <svg>
    <circle cx="76" cy="76" r="71" 
            style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

If you need the circle to be exactly that size (ie. 152 pixels), then you should make that the width and height of the SVG.

```html
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <svg width="152px" height="152px">
    <circle cx="76" cy="76" r="71" 
            style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

That solves your size problem.  To centre the SVG there are a couple of solutions:

1. Use CSS `margin` to centre the SVG in the div.

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <svg width="152px" height="152px">
    <circle cx="76" cy="76" r="71" 
            style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

2. Give the SVG a `viewBox` and have the browser automatically fit the SVG into the div. The advantage of this approach is that the SVG will automatically scale and centre within the div no matter how its size changes.

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 152 152">
    <circle cx="76" cy="76" r="71" 
            style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I figured it out later myself but your answer is 100% on point and informative for other reasons too, including points I missed and needed to know. Thanks.

Comment: LeBau. Can you please explain the space left at the bottom in your second example (out of the four).  That is the only missing link now in my understanding. I am using Chrome.

Comment: It is because `<svg>` elements are inline elements by default (ie. `display: inline`). So, like `<img>` elements, they will sit on the text baseline.  The extra space you see is the space where the descenders would be.  Descenders are the parts of character glyphs that hang below the baseline. The fix is to set `display: block` on the SVG element.

Comment: Terrific! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Should solve the truncation. `<svg>`'s default value is set to `overflow: hidden;` by default. Applying `overflow: visible;` to your `<svg>` should work.

Comment: It's much better for performance to make the svg bigger rather than using overflow: visible.

Comment: As Robert said, this is not a very good solution. See my answer for better alternatives.